# Use form field with select2 widget in smarty yii

Tags: widget, smarty, yii2

I would like to use this example from Kartik with Smarty.

```
use kartik\widgets\Select2

// Usage with ActiveForm and model
echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => array_merge(["" => ""], $data),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
     ],
]);
```

In Smarty only the field can be done with:

```
{$form->field($model, 'name')}
```

and only the widget:

```
{Select2
   name = 'my_selection'
   attribute = 'name'
   data = $data
   options = [
       'multiple' => true
   ]
}
```

I can't find how to combine these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work the same way. I have played with smarty a little and for me this works just fine

```
{$form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])}
```

For you it should be

```
{$form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => array_merge(["" => ""], $data),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
     ],
])}
```

If it does not work try not making multiple rows and put everything in 1 row.

This is how I have done it here: https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2-cms/blob/master/views/tag/_form.tpl